# Using bash/terminal to get number of battery recharge cycles

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, macos, battery, bash

I would like to get the number of recharge cycles using bash (terminal commands). I understand the following command will display all of the battery data, but I want the cycle count on its own

```
ioreg -l -w0 |grep Capacity
```

I use the following command to get the battery percentage, so I imagine it can be modified slightly to get the cycle count instead;

```
ioreg -l | awk '$3~/Capacity/{c[$3]=$5}END{OFMT="%.3f";max=c["\"MaxCapacity\""];print(max>0?100*c["\"CurrentCapacity\""]/max:"?")}'
```

I'm new to bash, so I'm not completely sure how that code works, or how I'd adapt it for my needs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Something like

```
system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Cycle Count" | awk '{print $3}'
```

should do the job.

```
system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Condition" | awk '{print $2}'
```

will get you the battery condition, for example: `Normal`.

If you want more output, run:

```
system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep -A3 -B7 "Condition"
```

to get something similar to this:

```
      Charge Information:
          Charge Remaining (mAh): 2405
          Fully Charged: No
          Charging: No
          Full Charge Capacity (mAh): 3816
      Health Information:
          Cycle Count: 187
          Condition: Normal
      Battery Installed: Yes
      Amperage (mA): -2635
      Voltage (mV): 11212
```

Comment: How about battery condition?

Comment: @BenSmith `system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Condition" | awk '{print $2}'` will get you the battery condition

Comment: Unfortunately `system_profiler` is not available in the safe boot environment.

Comment: If you're having problems doing this from Terminal in recovery mode, just run `chroot /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD zsh` first, then run the above commands

Answer (score 2):

```
system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep -A3 -B7 "Power"
```

I just do this, and it will do the things.