# Where are the files for System Information?

Tags: macos, system-information

I'm just curious if anyone knows where I can find the files that feed the data into the System Information Application (ATA, Audio, etc).

I am interested in writing a program that sends an email every time the battery cycle count increases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Information is a GUI for the CLI [system_profiler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/system_profiler.8.html). It's read directly from whatever `system_profiler` spits out. All the work is already done for you (`system_profiler` reads from many different files and executables):

!Just saw an answer posted. See @XAleXOwnZX for the exact command.

To compile that into a script within **Terminal**, enter text as follows. <kbd>Return</kbd> is supported for newlines after `cat` command.

```
$ cat > cycle
#! /bin/bash
#Output is current cycle count of the battery
system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Cycle Count" | awk '{print $3}' 
^D
```

- Now, you have the script. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> within terminal for a carriage return:
- Make executable with `chmod +x cycle`
- Test:

```
t$ ./cycle
4
```

- Move into your local bin, if it's included in your shell path. The file currently resides in your top user directory ~/

`$ mv cycle ~/bin/`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the file per-say, but you can use a simple shell script to get the battery cycle count, [as seen here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116429/using-bash-terminal-to-get-number-of-battery-recharge-cycles).

`system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Cycle Count" | awk '{print $3}'`