# Concatenating date and cycle count to file on startup

Tags: terminal, battery, system-settings

I have the following code from [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116429/using-bash-terminal-to-get-number-of-battery-recharge-cycles) to find the cycle count of the battery on my computer:

`system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Cycle Count" | awk '{print $3}'`

I will enclose it in a simple app that I will put in the Utilities folder in my applications folder as follows: NameofApp.sh.app->Contents->MacOS->NameofApp.sh. I will have it open on startup by means of System Preferences->Users and Groups->Login Items.

I was hoping to use the `date` command in terminal which gives output (As I'm sure you know) as `Tue Oct  7 19:32:33 EDT 2014`. I was hoping to delimit the date and the cycle count so I can easily separate it in excel.

The final product I was hoping for consist of a program that upon startup, prints the date + delimiter + cycle count to a new line in a text file (On desktop).

For example,

```
Tue Oct  7 19:32:33 EDT 2014#776
Tue Oct  8 13:55:02 EDT 2014#776
Tue Oct  8 21:23:16 EDT 2014#777
.
.
.
.
.
Tue Dec 12 07:34:56 EDT 2015#????
```

I'm having trouble combining the date with the output of the program above.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are You looking for a one liner command? I'm not sure if I understand the question. Here's my command:
`echo \`date\`#\`system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Cycle Count" | awk '{print $3}'\` >> output.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MateusvSzlosek, The following one-liner works:

```
echo `date`@`system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Cycle Count" | awk '{print $3}'` >> output.txt
```