# Macbook 2015 with normal battery won't charge even after SMC

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, charging, power-management

My MacBook won't charge. Here are the things I have done so far:

1. I tested the MagSafe charger to another laptop to make sure it is not faulty ( MagSafe is working )
2. I did the SMC reset ( shift + alt + control + power)
3. I decided to open the laptop, I pulled the clear plastic pull tab attached to the battery connector then try to plug the MagSafe. It lit up.
4. I attached the clear plastic pull tab attached to the battery connector back to the logic board then plug back the MagSafe, it does not light up.

Can anyone please give an idea of what seems to be the problem?

I checked the battery status using

```bsh
$ system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Condition" | awk '{print $2}'
condition: normal
```

The MacBook model is MacBook Air (13-inch, early 2015) macOS Mojave.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Apple.SE! Nice troubleshooting so far! Add MacBook model too! Maybe it's just old. Could you check the site for questions related to [tag:battery] problems? Also update us with the battery status using this command: `system_profiler SPPowerDataType | grep "Condition" | awk '{print $2}'` Source question: [Using bash/terminal to get number of battery recharge cycles](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116429/using-bash-terminal-to-get-number-of-battery-recharge-cycles)

Comment: Hi ankii, I checked the battery status using the command you gave (condition: normal). The macbook model is MacBook Air (13-inch, early 2015) MacOS Mojave

Comment: Can you also check the cycle count of the battery? If it is the original battery you got with your MBA in 2015 it may very well be beyond the expected number of cycles even if the condition is still shown as normal.

Comment: CoconutBattery is a good app for diagnosing battery issues as it queries all info the Mac has on the installed battery, age, charge, number of cycles and general battery health

Comment: I used what Steve recommended which is the coconutbattery, the cycle count is 509. Age 1,141 days, status Good, battery failure: none

Comment: When the battery is connected to the board, coconutBattery shows (Power Adapter: NOT CONNECTED). When I disconnect the battery from thr board coconutBattery shows (Power Adapter: CONNECTED)